# More than 50 android devices on same username/password

Tags: installation, multiple-devices

I have between 50-100 Android devices.  They are being used as a sensor network. Another 50 are coming online soon.  The devices need to download an app from the play store.  So I need to login with a google username/password.  For now, I have been using the same username/password on all the devices.  However, now google is asking me to resign in to the devices after a week or so.  This didn't happen before.  I think the number of devices on the same account is tripping some alarm.

Does anyone have any recomendations for how to set up 50+ devices so that they are all able to download and receive updates from the app store?

Answer (score 1):

Google Play won't let you do this. You can only have a few devices attached to each account at a time. This is to stop people abusing the facility of using paid content from any device on their account.

If the app is an open-source one, or it's under your control, you should distribute it to all your devices through a different mechanism (e.g. a custom app list on F-droid). Otherwise, you should contact the developer of the app and ask to make a volume licensing deal. Unless they're already dealing with enterprise customers, they won't be prepared for this situation, but I think most app developers will be willing to help you out for a reasonable bulk price.

Comment: The app is under my control.  The reason I've been using the app store is to get the automatic updating.  Is there a way to have many devices and still get the auto-updating, without building the auto-updating infrastructure?

Comment: Yeah: use a different app delivery platform that's not targeted for retail use. There are several third-party solutions; even if you roll your own, you can still use GCM to push the updates to clients.

Comment: I tried poking around.  Do you have a name or two for the third party solutions?

Comment: not yet tested... but a lead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213211/update-an-android-app-without-google-play

Comment: As app publishing questions are off-topic for this site, which deals with end-user questions only, I don't think it would be appropriate to recommend a distributor for your app.

Comment: i think if it answers the question it would be alright

Comment: "Is there a way to have many devices and still get the auto-updating, without building the auto-updating infrastructure?" Sure, just use different accounts for each device.